# Realm isn't set value to the fields of the objects on reflection (Android)

Tags: java, android, reflection, realm, abstraction

I'm trying to implement an abstraction to realm so that I could save some time when using the CURD operation on the db.

the abstraction that I build is `controller` to the database operation so that I could use this `controller` which do the CURD operation with any table.

i.e. the `controller` I'm talking about is just a Java `class` has four methods
`create` `update` `read` `delete`.

this is the `create` which using reflection to create the `db objects` and bind the fields of the passed `data object` to that `db object`

```
 /**
     * this method will delete the old data "you can change that"
     * of the table then store the passed data array in the table
     *
     * @param datum    the data Object you want to
     *                 save in the database
     * @param map      this map will contain which field
     *                 value in the data class will be
     *                 binded to which field in the db class
     *                 and will have this form dataFieldName => dbFieldName
     * @param callback when the function finish it's work it will
     *                 return a boolean value indicate whether
     *                 the function successfully finish it's work
     */
    public void create(
            Object datum,
            Class dataClass,
            HashMap<String, String> map,
            SaveDataCallback callback
    ) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(bgRealm -> {
                    long id;

                    Number currentId = bgRealm.where(clacc).max("id");//the clacc object is passed in the constructor of the controller  
                    if (currentId == null)
                        id = 1;
                    else
                        id = currentId.longValue() + 1;

                    RealmObject dbObject = bgRealm.createObject(clacc, id++);//the clacc object is passed in the constructor of the controller 
                    mapObjects(datum, dataClass, dbObject, clacc, map);



                }
                , () -> callback.onSavingDataFinished(true)
                , error -> callback.onSavingDataFinished(false));
    }


private void mapObjects(
            Object source,
            Class sourceClass,
            Object destination,
            Class destinationClass,
            HashMap<String, String> map) {
        String[] sourceFieldNames = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
                Field sourceField = sourceClass.getDeclaredField(sourceFieldNames[i]);
                sourceField.setAccessible(true);
                Object sourceValue = sourceField.get(source);

                String destinationFieldName = map.get(sourceFieldNames[i]);
                Field destinationField = destinationClass.getDeclaredField(destinationFieldName);
                destinationField.setAccessible(true);

                if (sourceField.getType() == Short.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Short.parseShort(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                if (sourceField.getType() == Integer.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Integer.parseInt(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                if (sourceField.getType() == Long.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Long.parseLong(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                if (sourceField.getType() == Float.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Float.parseFloat(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                if (sourceField.getType() == Double.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Double.parseDouble(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                if (sourceField.getType() == Byte.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Byte.parseByte(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                if (sourceField.getType() == Boolean.TYPE) {
                    destinationField.set(destination, Boolean.parseBoolean(sourceValue.toString()));
                    continue;
                }
                destinationField.set(destination, sourceValue);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

the problem is as follow:

when I'm trying to query the database to get the object after the finish of the process the database return the objects that I create using this function but those objects has no data `actually the returned data is set to default value to each type i.e. string to null boolean to false etc...`

my question is:

is there any problem in my code or the realm database doesn't support setting values to the objects on reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm doesn't support setting ***field*** values of managed objects via reflection.

It will however work if you call the setter methods through reflection.